# How to remap the English/Japanese input toggle shortcut (Alt + ` ) in Google IME?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language, japanese

I would like to remap the Alt + ` shortcut that allows one to switch between English and Japanese input to Ctrl + Space. How can I achieve this?

I presume the keys that I need to remap are "Activate IME" and "Deactivate IME" in the settings, I have tried changing the keybinds in the Google IME, but it seems that it only goes **one way**, where if I am in Japanese input, Ctrl + Space can go back to English, but it cannot go back to Japanese input from the English Input.

[image: Google IME]